# Shellscript! Syntax error: unexpected "("

Tags: shell-script, ssh, shutdown

After the changes from the first answer I got some more error codes.

```
: not found: line 23: {

esxidown.sh: line 24: redir error
Insufficient arguments.

: not found: line 26:

esxidown.sh: line 53: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")
```

I got a problem with a script I am trying to run.

The situation is: Me having a UPS and wanting to get a script which shuts down my VM's and afterwards shuts down the Host if the UPS starts running.

I already found a script that should safely shut down the VM's and then shut down the host.

But I get the following error: syntax error: unexpected "("

**Script without personal changes:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# ESXi 5.1 host automated shutdown script

# these are the VM IDs to shutdown in the order specified
# use the SSH shell, run "vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms" to get ID numbers
# specify IDs separated by a space
SERVERIDS=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}')

# New variable to allow script testing, assuming the vim commands all work to issue shutdowns
# can be "0" or "1"
TEST=0

# script waits WAIT_TRYS times, WAIT_TIME seconds each time
# number of times to wait for a VM to shutdown cleanly before forcing power off.
WAIT_TRYS=20

# how long to wait in seconds each time for a VM to shutdown.
WAIT_TIME=10

# ------ DON'T CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE ------

validate_shutdown()
{
    vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate $SRVID | grep -i "off" > /dev/null 2<&1
    STATUS=$?

    if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
if [ $TRY -lt $WAIT_TRYS ]; then
        # if the vm is not off, wait for it to shut down
        TRY=$((TRY + 1))
        echo "Waiting for guest VM ID $SRVID to shutdown (attempt #$TRY)..."
        sleep $WAIT_TIME
        validate_shutdown
    else
        # force power off and wait a little (you could use vmsvc/power.suspend here instead)
        echo "Unable to gracefully shutdown guest VM ID $SRVID... forcing power off."
        if [ $TEST -eq 0 ]; then
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off $SRVID
        fi
sleep $WAIT_TIME
    fi
fi
}

# enter maintenance mode immediately
echo "Entering maintenance mode..."
if [ $TEST -eq 0 ]; then
esxcli system maintenanceMode set -e true -t 0 &
fi

# read each line as a server ID and shutdown/poweroff
for SRVID in $SERVERIDS
do
TRY=0

vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate $SRVID | grep -i "off\|Suspended" > /dev/null 2<&1
STATUS=$?

if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Attempting shutdown of guest VM ID $SRVID..."
    if [ $TEST -eq 0 ]; then
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.shutdown $SRVID
    fi
validate_shutdown
else
echo "Guest VM ID $SRVID already off..."
fi
done

# guest vm shutdown complete
echo "Guest VM shutdown complete..."

# shutdown the ESXi host
echo "Shutting down ESXi host after 10 seconds..."
if [ $TEST -eq 0 ]; then
esxcli system shutdown poweroff -d 10 -r "Automated ESXi host shutdown - esxidown.sh"
fi

# exit maintenance mode immediately before server has a chance to shutdown/power off
# NOTE: it is possible for this to fail, leaving the server in maintenance mode on reboot!
echo "Exiting maintenance mode..."
if [ $TEST -eq 0 ]; then
esxcli system maintenanceMode set -e false -t 0
fi

# exit the session
exit
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `SERVERIDS=1 2 3 4(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}')`

Comment: This is a script I got from this article: http://www.nojokeit.com/2012/11/graceful-shutdown-of-esxi-51-host-free.html
1 2 3 4 are the Server ID's from my virtual machines. I think in this line the script is trying to say that 1 2 3 4 are the ID's and where to find them. So the script can check them. But I am really new to this stuff so I am not sure.

Comment: I suggest you go do some reading on how to write shell scripts. If you want to know what's going on inside of there do: `sh -vx /path/to/script`

Comment: @Timo The script pasted in your question seems different from the one in the link mentioned.  It seems that you have introduced typos.

Comment: I edited my VM ID's. 
Original: SERVERIDS=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}')

My Version with VM ID's: SERVERIDS=1 2 3 4(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}')

Did I understand this wrong?

Comment: Please put the full current code in your question, properly formatted. Doing mental diffs on code when trying to sort out syntax errors is *really* hard.

Comment: I added the script how I downloaded it. Without any changes from my side.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
SERVERIDS=1 2 3 4(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}')
```

This will set `SERVERIDS=1` for that command only and then runs the "command" `2` with the arguments `3` and `4(...)`, the latter of which is not valid syntax. [Using more quotes](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes&ei=kaNXU4qyI6nT7AavkoDYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGCW99ARZBuQx2ZPTMwe3zrVlIcnw&sig2=-V4VEn7RBBVyMtYVUC5Eog&bvm=bv.65177938,d.ZGU), you probably want something like this:

```
SERVERIDS="1 2 3 4 $(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}')"
```